# Angular Signup page using ui-router not able to access the html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular sign-up page. This is the directory structure of my project:

```
    singUpPage-Angular
    bin
    bower_components
    model
      mongodbApp.js
    node_modules
    **partials
        fail.html
        main.html
        success.html**
    public
    images
    **javascripts
        signUp.js**
    stylesheets
    routes
      index.js
      users.js
    **views
        index.ejs**
    app.js
    package.json
```

All my html is in partials folder
The javascript controller code is in signup.js
The main html is in views index.ejs.

I have tried to acces the html using the ui router and the code is not working. I am not sure if itis an error with the path or if there is a prolem with ui-router code.

The router does not take me to the page:

When I run the code: on the address bar I get: http://localhost:3000/#/partials/main.html: but nothing from the main page get displayed. I dont seem to get an errors either.

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
      <script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/javascripts/signUp.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div ui-view></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**signUp.js**

```
angular.module("myApp",['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('partials/main.html');
    $stateProvider
        .state('success', {
            url: "/success",
            templateUrl:'partials/success.html'
        })
        .state('fail', {
            url: '/fail',
            templateUrl:'partials/fail.html'
        })

})
    .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, SignUp,$state){

        $scope.clearPerson = function(){
        $scope.first = "";
        $scope.last = "";
        $scope.email = "";
        $scope.password = "";
        $scope.confirm = "";
        $scope.dob = "";
        }



        $scope.addPerson = function(){
           /* console.log($scope.first);
            console.log($scope.last);
            console.log($scope.email);
            console.log($scope.password);
            console.log($scope.confirm);
            console.log($scope.dob);*/
            $scope.person = {
                firstName: $scope.first,
                lastName: $scope.last,
                email: $scope.email,
                password:$scope.password,
                dateOfBirth: $scope.dob
            }

            console.log($scope.person);
            SignUp.add($scope.person).success(function(res){
                $state.go("success");
                console.log(res);
            }).error(function(res){
                $state.go("fail");
                console.log("error");
            })

        }

    })
   .factory("SignUp", function($http){
        return{
               add: function(person){
                return $http.post('/signup',person);
            }
        }
    })
```

**main.html**

```
    <h1>Sign up Page</h1>
<div class="new-container">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Create an ID</h3>

        <form class="form-horizontal" name="signup" novalidate ng-submit="addPerson()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Name</h4>
                <label  class="col-sm-2 label-control align-text" >First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-margin" >
                    <input name="first"  ng-maxlength=50 ng-model="first" type="text" class="form-control"  required>
                    <div class="error"
                         ng-show="signup.first.$dirty && signup.first.$invalid">
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.first.$error.required">
                            Your name is required.
                        </small>
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.first.$error.maxlength">
                            Your name cannot be longer than 50 characters
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 label-control align-text" >Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-margin">
                    <input name="last"  ng-maxlength=50 ng-model="last" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="optional">
                    <div class="error"
                         ng-show="signup.last.$dirty && signup.last.$invalid">
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.last.$error.maxlength">
                            Your name cannot be longer than 50 characters
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>ID and Password</h4>
                <label class="col-sm-2 align-text label-control">Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-margin">
                    <input name="email" ng-maxlength=56 ng-model="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <div class="error"
                         ng-show="signup.email.$dirty && signup.email.$invalid">
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.email.$error.required">
                            Your email is required.
                        </small>
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.email.$error.maxlength">
                            Your name cannot be longer than 56 characters
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 label-control align-text">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-margin">
                    <input name="password" ng-minlength=6 ng-model="password" type="password" class="form-control al" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <div class="error"
                         ng-show="signup.password.$dirty && signup.password.$invalid">
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.password.$error.required">
                            Your password is required.
                        </small>
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.password.$error.minlength">
                            Your name cannot be atleast 6 characters long.
                        </small>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 label-control align-text">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-margin">
                    <input name="confirm" compare-to="password" ng-model="confirm" type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" required>
                    <div class="error"
                         ng-show="signup.confirm.$dirty && signup.confirm.$invalid">
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.confirm.$error.required">
                            Password confirmation is required.
                        </small>
                        <small class="error"
                               ng-show="signup.confirm.$error.errorCompareTo">
                            Your passwords do not match.
                        </small>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Date of Birth</h4>
                <label  class="col-sm-2 label-control align-text">Birthday</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-margin">
                    <input ng-model="dob" type="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" >
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 float-right" >
                    <button type="submit" class="btn signUp" >Sign Up</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clearPerson()">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fail.html**

```
<h1>fail</h1>
```

**success.html**

```
<h1>success</h1>
```

Comment: `the code is not working` is a poor problem description. What exactly doesn't work? Which files are loaded from the server? Show the network protocol? What server do you use and how is it configured? Where did you set the the default page (index.ejs)?

Comment: Please format your question properly. It is extremely tough to comprehend what you are trying to convey. *Totally agree with Michael above

Answer (score 0):

```
Do this
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

In State
     $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl:'partials/main.html'
        })
```

This will open your signUpPage

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work. Now my address bar doesnt point to main.html. It shows: http://localhost:3000/#/. I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What your app name? singUpPage?    then  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/singUpPage');    In state url: /'singUpPage'